# Bind Dropdown with hardcoded values

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, bind

I have a dropdown list with hard coded values:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="BulletinTypeDropDown" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="--Select--" Value="--Select--"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="News" Value="News"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="report" Value="report"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="System" Value="System"></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Text="Reminder" Value="Reminder"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I want to use this to insert and edit values from a db. For example when adding a record the user selects 'report' and 'report' gets inserted into the database. Then if the user goes to edit the page since the value in the db is 'report' then the dropdownlist must show 'report' is selected.
But i am able to store the value in DB successfully but i couldn't retrieve the selected page during the edit page.
I am using Entity frame work so, i tired to so many ways but couldn't get the value in edit page.
Here is the way i tried.

`DropDown.SelectedValue = bulList.intype.ToString();`//intype is the value i am getting from DB and it is returning the currect value but passing null in the DropDown.selectedvalue.

Can somebody please help me what are the other ways i can work to get the values in my dropdown list.

Thanks

Comment: At what eventhandler in the page lifecycle do you try to set the dropdownlist-value (Page_load,Button_click)? How does the editpage receive the value? Its easier when you show some more code.

Comment: i am trying to show the dropdownlist at page_load.I have just hardcoded those values and in dropdownlist and in code behind i tired i am just doing as below, if (bulletinList.Bulletintype != null)
            {
              
              BulletinTypeDropDown.SelectedValue = bulletinList.Bulletintype;}

Comment: When are you setting the read value from the database? Perhaps your dropdown doesn't have the hard-coded Items yet at the time the SelectedValue is set? Break on the line where SelectedValue is set and check the Items.Length.

Comment: When you hit Page_load with the debugger do you see that bulList.intype is realy set to the value you expect?

Comment: Yes i see the value in bulList.intype but not in dropdownlist.Drodownlist is always showing the default value.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find the text on the dropdownlist and set the selected property to true
Example:

```
//pass the string you want to set selected to true --> assuming in your case bulList.intype.ToString()
BulletinTypeDropDown.Items.FindByText(bulList.intype.ToString()).Selected = true;
```

You can also do similar by using FindByValue. More information here: http://forums.asp.net/t/1004541.aspx/1

Comment: I tried even this but it was throwing an error saying that..Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Check bulList.intype.ToString() is some text that is not null and it's value matches the items in your DropDown list.

Comment: bulList.intype.ToString() is passing exact value that is in DB but Dropdownlist is always passing --select--.

Comment: Maybe you should remove Selected="True" for the first Item. You will get that anyway when page load first time since it is first one on your list. Also use bulList.intype.ToString().Trim() so that it clears any space that could be in DB value. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
BulletinTypeDropDown.SelectedValue = valueFromDb;
```

Comment: i did the same thing but VlauefromDb is giving me the value from Db but BulletinTypeDropdown.selectedvalue is not assigning the value from DB its always showing --select-- value.

Comment: My guess would be that `DropDownList1_Load` is being called after you assign the `SelectedValue` from the database. Set some breakpoints and verify.

Answer (score 0):

So the dropdownlist stays on default value, if so find a binding method in your code probably inside page load. 
Otherwise if `bulList.intype` is returning the value there is no way I think the dropdownlist refuses to show selected value. May be check the returned value for spaces. Try this:

```
string s =  = bulList.intype.ToString().Trim();
DropDown.SelectedValue = s;
```

Comment: No luck, i tried By assigning Trim(), but its still showing me the same as before.The String S showing me correct value but when it comes to DropDown.SelectedValue is still showing me as --select--

Answer (score 0):

Here is soultion that may work for you.
so create your dropdown list.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
        onload="DropDownList1_Load" >
    </asp:DropDownList>


protected void DropDownList1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        List<string> DDLlist = new List<string>();
        DDLlist.Add("Report");
        DDLlist.Add("News");
        DropDownList1.DataSource = DDLlist;
        DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "Report";
        DropDownList1.DataBind();
    }
```

You can add to the DDLlist to add new items dynamically.

Comment: I tried this and i am getting what i wanted, but the problem is in the dropdown i see all the values assign to all the values id's.but i wanted only distinct items in dropdownlist.

Comment: can you give me more details on what you are wanting in the list to appear.